# how to modify the appearance of a checkboxlist to it look like buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I thought it would be easy, but I'm not being able to find how to do it. I found how to do it with a checkbox ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.appearance.aspx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.appearance.aspx).

But, how could do it with the checkboxlist control?

Comment: can you use jQuery ? if true, you can wrap the DOM in a more fashioned ui

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that I could change the style to a ToggleButton (http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20ToggleButton%20Control.ashx), and I guess it would work.
But I'm asking for a simpler way. If there exist an attribute which allows to do it or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve B suggested, a nice way is to use jQuery. I put a checkbox inside a asp:Repeater control, and I modify the appearance of this checkbox to look like a button. This is the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterVocabularyWords" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterVocabularyWords_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span class="storeCheck">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxVocabularyWord" Font-Size="0px" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>"
                ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="{labelOn: '<%# Container.DataItem %>', labelOff: '<%# Container.DataItem %>', easing: 'easeOutBounce', duration: 500}" />
        </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in the code behind:

```
String [] wordsForButtons = new[] { "text1", "text2", "text3" };               
RepeaterVocabularyWords.DataSource = wordsForButtons;
RepeaterVocabularyWords.DataBind();
```

I hope it is useful for somebody!

Carlos